# Tunnelblick won't run after Time Machine restore to a ne mac

Tags: vpn

I use Tunnelblick on a daily basis to connect to my work network.
It used to run great, however after I got a new mac and restored data from a time machine backup, issues began.

First, let's clear the obvious: after restoration, I was asked to confirm the developer of the extension and so i did.

Second, Tunnelblick worked several times after the restore. It was maybe 2-3 times, however with issues. I had to reboot the system to make it work.

Now it doesn't work at all, I am greeted with the following:

[image]

The logs contain:

```
Could not start OpenVPN (openvpnstart returned with status #247)

Contents of the openvpnstart log:
*Tunnelblick: openvpnstart log:
     Loading tap-signed.kext
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     stderr from kextload: /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
     Unable to load net.tunnelblick.tun and/or net.tunnelblick.tap kexts in 5 tries. Status = 71
```

I am on the latest High Sierra, so i have stumbled upon:
https://tunnelblick.net/cKextLoadErrorHighSierra.html

But no, it's not blocked, I have already allowed it!

I have tried uninstalling Tunnelblick using the official Uninstall app and I have reinstalled, but nothing has changed.

I have tried to check what's up with the kexts:

```
(kernel) Kext net.tunnelblick.tap start failed (result 0x5).
(kernel) Kext net.tunnelblick.tap failed to load (0xdc008017).
(kernel) Failed to load kext net.tunnelblick.tap (error 0xdc008017).
Failed to load /Library/StagedExtensions/Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-signed.kext - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed.
```

I don't have any other vpn related KEXTs loaded, which could interfere:

```
>kextstat | egrep '(cisco|vpn|tap|tun)'
>
```

I will appreciate any help with this, some hint, where to look next?

EDIT:
I thought i have added that already, but manual loading of the kext fails:

```
sudo kextload /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-signed.kext
Password:
/Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/tap-signed.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) kext (kmod) start/stop routine failed; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
```

and the logs are above.

Comment: well the driver is still not loading

Comment: did you try sudo kextload /path/to/kext.kext

Comment: @Buscar웃 sorry, thought I have added that before, updated question.